# C# connection issue

Tags: c#

My first issue: I am trying to establish connection to MySql database, but I keep getting error when I debug it with Visual Studio:"**Connection must be valid and open.**"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Threading;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql.Data.Types; 


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MySqlConnection conn;
        string myConnectionString;
        myConnectionString = "server=localhost;User Id=root;database=test3";
        using (conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString))
        {
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM department");
            // sleep for 2.5s
            Thread.Sleep(2500);

            conn.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            conn.Close();


        }


    }
 }
```

My second issue: if there a way to display all this on a ASP.NET Web form (I want to leave code on server side), but display data something like ListView or GridView? Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#p28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call conn.Open() before using it.

Comment: Thanks, I did work, but do you know how can I display all this on a web form?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to attach your connection to the command:

```
cmd.Connection = conn;
```

Comment: Thanks, I dis work, but also want to display all those result from SELECT query on a web form? Do you how could I achieve this? Any tutorials?